# error while loading shared libraries: libqjson.so.0

Tags: software-installation, sql

I've installed sqlprofiler but I'm getting following error

```
$ sqlprofiler
sqlprofiler: error while loading shared libraries: libqjson.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Ubuntu 64 Bit 18.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is provided by package [`libqjson0`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libqjson0/filelist).

```
sudo apt install libqjson0
```

Try again `sqlprofiler` then.

You can use the https://packages.ubuntu.com/ to search for the package containing a specific file, in your case [searching “package contents” for “libqjson.so.0”](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&searchon=contents&keywords=libqjson.so.0) gives `libqjson0` as the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out :)

Comment: @KaushalSuthar Please consider filing a bug on the sqlprofiler package. libqjson0 should be a dependency, but obviously it is no explicit dependency. This should be fixed by the maintainer.

Comment: @allo I've already informed them about this, But I'm not sure that they will reply on it.